# How to reference array from inside method to outside method ?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my android app project, before this activity, I have a class that send variables via intent. So now, I want to send it again to another activity, it cannot send via Intent anymore because I already make adapter class (to make list view). Help Me,, I really confuse with this

Activity :

```
  public class KantorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kantor);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, getKantors());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


       searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });


        }


     public ArrayList<Kantor> getKantors(){
            Intent next = getIntent();
            String[] namaKantor = next.getStringArrayExtra("namaKantor");
            int [] gambar = next.getIntArrayExtra("gambar");
            String[] desk = next.getStringArrayExtra("desk");

            ArrayList<Kantor> kantors = new ArrayList<Kantor>();
            Kantor k;

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences
                    ("id.ac.unsyiah.elektro.mobile.pservices", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


            this.namaKantor=namaKantor; //...?
           this.gambar=gambar; //...?
            this.desk=desk; //.....?

            for (int i=0;i<namaKantor.length;i++){
                k =new Kantor(namaKantor[i], gambar[i], desk[i]);
                kantors.add(k);
            }
            return kantors;
        }

            String[]namaKantor; //HOW TO REFERENCE THIS ARRAY TO ARRAY inside method above??
            String []desk; //HOW TO REFERENCE THIS ARRAY TO ARRAY inside method above??
            int [] gambar; //HOW TO REFERENCE THIS ARRAY TO ARRAY inside method above??
        }
```

Adapter :

```
    package id.ac.unsyiah.elektro.mobile.pservices;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Kantor> kantors;
    CustomFilter filter;
    ArrayList<Kantor> filterList;

    public Adapter(Context c,ArrayList<Kantor>kantors){
        this.c=c;
        this.kantors=kantors;
        this.filterList=kantors;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return kantors.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return kantors.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
        }
        //tampilan
        ImageView img= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgModel);
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.namaModel);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deskModel);

        //set data
        img.setImageResource(kantors.get(pos).getImg());
        tv.setText(kantors.get(pos).getNama());
        tv2.setText(kantors.get(pos).getDesk());

        //itemClick
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OpenDetail(pos);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

//THIS IS FOR OPEN ANOTHER ACTIVITY VIA INTENT
    private void OpenDetail (int pos) {
            Intent next = new Intent(c, DetailActivity.class);
           next.putExtra("pos", pos);
            c.startActivity(next);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(filter==null){
            filter=new CustomFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    class CustomFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint !=null & constraint.length()>0){
                constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

                ArrayList<Kantor> filters=new ArrayList<Kantor>();

                for(int i=0;i<filterList.size();i++){
                    if (filterList.get(i).getNama().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        Kantor k = new Kantor(filterList.get(i).getNama(), filterList.get(i).getImg(),filterList.get(i).getDesk());
                        filters.add(k);
                    }
                }
                results.count=filters.size();
                results.values=filters;
            }
            else{
                results.count=filterList.size();
                results.values=filterList;
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            kantors= (ArrayList<Kantor>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can pass the  data to other intent. Adapter class doesn't stop you

Comment: how? where I can put the Intent (activity or adapter class),,? because in adapter already have method OpenDetail to open another activity and send Intent (only send the position),, is it possible to send it from activity? or maybe possible to reference it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to brief a little more . Based on what you have provided . I agree , with @PradeepCharan . Intent can surely be called any number of times by simply , calling :

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
```

After this , extract , any value that you have been wanting to **reuse**

What is confusing you , is a wonder !

Comment: So, from this activity to another activity, I send intent again? But, where I put the intent,,,?
On Activity class or Adapter Class (in adapter class have a method onClick). I already tried both but fail?

Comment: You send intent only once . And get as many times , as you want . You can refer to data by their "KEY" . Get the intent , in whatsoever activity you want to use the data in . Accept the answer , if it solves the purpose .